# How do I use external Javascript libraries in Keystone Js?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js, keystone

I'm currently building a node website using keystone js. On the pages of the website, I'm using javascript libraries, such as swiper, to render some of the visuals. However, it seems that keystone is not picking up the js libraries I've included. Does anyone know why and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised that I have to put all the js scripts in the default.jade template. After that it all works just as I intended it to be.